# How to convert cv2 image to skimage?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image, image-conversion

I am reading an image from a camera that comes in `cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR` format. Below is a temporary work around for what I am trying to achieve:

```
import cv2
from skimage import transform, io

...
_, img = cam.read()
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imwrite("temp.png", img)
img = io.imread("temp.png", as_gray=True)
img = transform.resize(img, (320, 240), mode='symmetric', preserve_range=True)
```

---

I found one way to do this conversion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855615/skimage-io-imread-versus-cv2-imread), however, it seems that the image data is not the same than if I read the same image from a path?

I've also found from [this documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html) that I can use `img_as_float(cv2_img)`, but this conversion does not produce the same result as what is returned by `io.imread("temp.png", as_gray=True)`

---

**What is the proper way to do this conversion efficiently? Should I first convert the image back to RGB then use img_as_float()?**

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of necessary details, and it's quite confusing, to be honest. I assume, `_, img = cam.read()` is the OpenCV VideoCapture call!? Then, why do you convert using `cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR`? `img` already is in BGR color space when using OpenCV functions. Then, you save a color image, but load that image as grayscale!? What conversion do you actually want to achieve? Can you please describe the desired conversion in words? In general: OpenCV images are skimage images, since both libraries use NumPy arrays for image representation. Color space, handling data types vary, yes.

Comment: @HansHirse I referenced in the question that that is the incoming format of the cv2 image I am receiving. The code is for illustration but I do not actually have control over the first 2 lines. From what I understand using io.imread(as_grey) would produce a slightly different image than converting the image to greyscale using cv2.

Comment: @HansHirse all I need to do is convert this cv2 bgr image to a skimage that would be indentical as if I first saved the image to disk and then reloaded the image using io.imread(), because again, I read that direct conversion from the methods I found would Yield a similar but slightly different image than writing and then reloading. I’m also asking if I’m wrong about this assumption as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, the basic problem you encounter, are the different [luma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Luma_coding_in_video_systems) calculations used by OpenCV and scikit-image:

- [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html) uses:

  ```
  Y = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B
  ```
- [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_rgb_to_gray.html) uses:

  ```
  Y = 0.2125 * R + 0.7154 * G + 0.0721 * B
  ```

Let's have some tests – using the following image for example:

[image: Paddington]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io

# Assuming we have some kind of "OpenCV image", i.e. BGR color ordering
cv2_bgr = cv2.imread('paddington.png')

# Convert to grayscale
cv2_gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv2_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Save BGR image
cv2.imwrite('cv2_bgr.png', cv2_bgr)

# Save grayscale image
cv2.imwrite('cv2_gray.png', cv2_gray)

# Convert to grayscale with custom luma
cv2_custom_luma = np.uint8(0.2125 * cv2_bgr[..., 2] + 0.7154 * cv2_bgr[..., 1] + 0.0721 * cv2_bgr[..., 0])

# Load BGR saved image using scikit-image with as_gray; becomes np.float64
sc_bgr_w = io.imread('cv2_bgr.png', as_gray=True)

# Load grayscale saved image using scikit-image without as_gray; remains np.uint8
sc_gray_wo = io.imread('cv2_gray.png')

# Load grayscale saved image using scikit-image with as_gray; remains np.uint8
sc_gray_w = io.imread('cv2_gray.png', as_gray=True)

# OpenCV grayscale = scikit-image grayscale loaded image without as_gray? Yes.
print('Pixel mismatches:', cv2.countNonZero(cv2.absdiff(cv2_gray, sc_gray_wo)))
# Pixel mismatches: 0

# OpenCV grayscale = scikit-image grayscale loaded image with as_gray? Yes.
print('Pixel mismatches:', cv2.countNonZero(cv2.absdiff(cv2_gray, sc_gray_w)))
# Pixel mismatches: 0

# OpenCV grayscale = scikit-image BGR loaded (and scaled) image with as_gray? No.
print('Pixel mismatches:', cv2.countNonZero(cv2.absdiff(cv2_gray, np.uint8(sc_bgr_w * 255))))
# Pixel mismatches: 131244

# OpenCV grayscale with custom luma = scikit-image BGR loaded (and scaled) image with as_gray? Almost.
print('Pixel mismatches:', cv2.countNonZero(cv2.absdiff(cv2_custom_luma, np.uint8(sc_bgr_w * 255))))
# Pixel mismatches: 1
```

You see:

- When opening the grayscale image, scikit-image simply uses the `np.uint8` values, regardless of using `as_gray=True` or not.
- When opening the color image with `as_gray=True`, scikit-image applies `rgb2gray`, scales all values to `0.0 ... 1.0`, thus uses `np.float64`. Even scaling back to `0 ... 255` and `np.uint8` yields a lot of pixel mismatches between this image and the OpenCV grayscale image – due to the different luma calculations.
- When calculating the luma manually and accordingly to `rgb2gray`, the OpenCV grayscale image is almost identical. The one pixel mismatch might be due to floating point inaccuracies.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
NumPy:         1.20.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
scikit-image:  0.18.1
----------------------------------------
```